# python : print output of each thread to seperate file no processes

Tags: python, multithreading, logging

I have several threads and each thread writes output to stdout. However I want to redirect the ouput of each thread to a separate file independently of each other, then merge them to keep he flow of each thread together.

What I mean is the following:

Thread1 writes every print, every exception and every other ouput into file1.log
Thread2 writes every print, every exception and every other ouput into file2.log
and so on.
So what I'm looking for is to set the stdout for each thread exclusivly. However setting the stdout only works globally mean that Thread1 and Tread2 will always write to the same defined stdout. I have not found out yet how to do this. 
I can't use processes though, because f another issue.

How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe [this idea](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/40523/) helps?

Answer (score 7):

The Python [**`logging`**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module is [thread-safe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#thread-safety).

Use it to create an individual logger for each thread, and register a [`FileHandler`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.FileHandler) to (also) log to a file:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('thread-1')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('thread-1.log')
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Here's a more complete example:

```
import logging
import random
import threading
import time

NUM_THREADS = 5


def worker(delay, logger):
    """A toy worker function, taking the logger as an argument.
    """
    logger.info("Starting work...")
    for i in range(3):
        logger.info('Sleeping %0.02f', delay)
        time.sleep(delay)
    logger.info('Done.')


for n in range(1, NUM_THREADS + 1):
    # create the thread's logger
    logger = logging.getLogger('thread-%s' % n)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # create a file handler writing to a file named after the thread
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('thread-%s.log' % n)

    # create a custom formatter and register it for the file handler
    formatter = logging.Formatter('(%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    # register the file handler for the thread-specific logger
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    delay = random.random()
    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(delay, logger))
    t.start()


main_thread = threading.currentThread()
for t in threading.enumerate():
    if t is not main_thread:
        t.join()
```

This will give you five logfiles, `thread-1.log` through `thread-5.log`, containing only the output of the respective thread:

**`thread-1.log`**

```
(Thread-1  ) Starting work...
(Thread-1  ) Sleeping 0.53
(Thread-1  ) Sleeping 0.53
(Thread-1  ) Sleeping 0.53
(Thread-1  ) Done.
```

---

If you still want to log to the console, simply create a [`StreamHandler`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#streamhandler) and attach it to your logger:

```
stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
```

This will log to `STDERR` by default. If you want `STDOUT`, use

```
logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
```

For more information on using the Python `logging` module, see the [Advanced Logging Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial).

Comment: i have two limitationg thuogh-
1. i can't use logger.info, i must use print, and use python 2.x, the rest of the project uses prints.
2. i don't want the print to print to screen, just to files, and after that print ordered files to screen

Comment: Well, you didn't mention this requirement anywhere in your question. Also, **why** do you have to use `print`? The `print` statement is not thread-safe, and you're writing a multi-threaded application. You want to log - use the `logging` module, that's exactly what's it's for.

Comment: i need to use print because the rest of the code using print, and this is too much to change.
isn't there an option to get the same result using print?

Comment: You *will* need to change that - as I said, `print` isn't thread-safe, and shouldn't be used in production code to log.

Comment: @LukasGraf What if you also want stderr/stdout produced by each thread to stay separated? That is, information gets output other than by the python code explicitly (say, an os.system() call, or even a python segfault) that I'd want in the individual thread logs - is something like that possible?